# Java 3D segments intersection

Tags: geometry, segments

I'm looking for the best way to find out an intersection between two 3D segments(and/or two 3D straight lines) using Java.

For what I understood while looking for it through Google, it seems that the best thing to do is to use the [Java3D library](https://java3d.java.net/).

But even using that I really can't find out how, the intersect class of the library is deprecated, and when I look for a solution through Google I always end up finding confusing piece of code directed to solve a way more bigger problem than mine.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you seen "The shortest line between two lines in 3D" chapter here http://paulbourke.net/geometry/pointlineplane/  ?

Comment: Well I guess I can try to find the shortest line and then if the line has length 0 I can use one of its point to know where the intersection is.
But what I was trying to find was a "clearer" method and possibly one which was managed by a library.
But, thank you anyway for your help.

Comment: Anyway, you have to check if lines lie in the same plane (not skew), i.e. mixed product (determinant) is zero (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_lines), that takes a lot of calculations too

Answer (score -1):

Personally I like using the apache commons library

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.geometry.euclidean.threed.Line;
```

and

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.geometry.euclidean.threed.Vector3D;
```

are the imports that you need. To do an intersection, declare lines it is prety easy just make a line and do a .intersection()